# Subida de archivo a ftp a traves de Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Buenos dias. Estoy tratando de hacer un formulario que sube ficheros a un ftp usando PHP. El problema esta en que se recarga la pagina cuando se ejecuta la subida. Se que para que solo se refresque una zona hay que usar AJAX, pero no consigo ejecutar la subida usandolo. A continuacion muestro el formulario HTML:

```
<form id="subida" action="php/upload-ftp.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
  <div>  
  <label for="upload">Selecciona un fichero</label>  
  <input name="upload" type="file" id="file" />  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnUpload"/>  
  </div>  
</form>
```

Este HTML dirige al siguiente PHP que ejecuta la subida con exito:

```
<?php
```

$destino = $_COOKIE['ruta']."/subidas/";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

```
  if (!empty($_FILES['upload']['name'])) {  
    $ch = curl_init();  
    $localfile = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];  
    $fp = fopen($localfile, "r");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "URL_de_FTP+PUERTO/".$destino.$_FILES['upload']['name']);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));  
    curl_exec ($ch);  
    $error_no = curl_errno($ch);  
    curl_close ($ch);  
    if ($error_no == 0) {  
      $error = "Fichero subido correctamente.";  
    } else {  
      $error = "Error al subir el fichero.";  
    }  
  } else {  
    $error = "Selecciona un fichero.";  
  }  
}
```

?>

La pregunta es, ¿como ejecutar este proceso a través de AJAX? He intentado de diversas formas, pero nunca he logrado que funcione. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sendForm(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formd = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    $.ajax({
            url: event.currentTarget.getAttribute('action'),
            method: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(r){
//La respuesta ha ido bien y esta grabada en la variable r
},
            error: function(er){
                alert('Error de Formulario');
            }
    });
}
```

Al formulario pon:

```
getElementById().addEventListener('submit',sendForm(),false);
```